# Git diff changed in local branch but not in master

Tags: git

I've done some searching around but I couldn't find an answer for this question.  Answers that I have come across either aren't quite what I'm looking for or, for those that seem like they should work don't.

So here's our development process.  We have a remote master branch.  When working on new functionality, a developer will create a new branch and work in it.  When development has finish, the developer merges into the remote master.  On a regular basis, other devs pull down and merge those changes into their development branch so that they are always working with the current codebase.  All of this is routine and is a very typical workflow.

What I'm trying to do is get a list of those files that are different between my branch and the remote master (i.e., those changes that I haven't yet merged into master).  When I try the various suggestions I've found out there on the web (e.g., `git diff --name-only master...` and variations thereof) it shows me everything that I've checked into my branch, including those that were a result of the regular merges down from master. And since I'm the one doing the merging, I can't even do `git diff --name-only --author="Christoph" master...` (or variations thereof).

So is there a way to get a list of those files that contain changes present in my branch that don't appear in the remote master repository?

thnx,
Christoph

Comment: @eftshift0, both of those are essentially saying the same thing.  "Changes that I haven't yet merged into master" are those changes that exist only on my local branch.  The second statement says pretty much that.

```git diff --name-only HEAD...origin/master```

returns nothing.  It just dumps me back at the prompt.

```git diff --name-only origin/master...HEAD```

gives me a list of a ton of files.  Most of which include files that other devs merged into the remote master after their development completed and that I merged down from the remote master to my local branch so I'm current

Comment: Actually, you are correct.... and what you want should be provided with `git diff --name-only origin/master...HEAD`.